# SQL Server cannot set application role after changed password

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, application-role

Originally, my application can change application role by command.

```
exec sp_setapprole 'ARole', {ENCRYPT N'PASS01'}
```

And after I changed the application role's password to 'PASS02', I found

```
exec sp_setapprole 'ARole', {ENCRYPT N'PASS02'}
```

wouldn't work and returns an incorrect password.

I found it works after I changed the code to

```
1)   exec sp_setapprole 'ARole', 'PASS02' 
    -- or  -- 
2)   exec sp_setapprole 'ARole', 'PASS02', 'ODBC'
```

What puzzles me is why the original code is working? And how the password was set at the first place ?